# Did a Century/W-Body/GM Issue Exist Due to Chafing Wires Under the Dash?

Tags: electrical, buick, gm, factory-flaws, w-body

I am trying to find out if an issue is a common flaw.

Sixth Generation Buick Century's (1997-2005) Maybe all W-Bodies, or even all GM's of the era, I am not sure.

But lets focus on Sixth Gen Century's, for now.

I remember seeing all kinds of electrical gremlins being attributed to a "flaw" where a portion of the main harness under the dash (about where the drivers right knee is USDM) would chafe. Now I am trying to find information on it, and I am doubting my sanity, as usual.

Has anyone else heard about this? Anyone have any more information? I remember there was a YouTube video of a guy doing a No Crank/No Start/Black-Out diag with a (?red?) Century in a field, the interior was kind of stripped and the guy talks about reaching under the dash and jiggling the wires and, sure enough, power comes back.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Sounds similar to a fault that used to happen on alpines / solaras back in the day, but could also be a loose connector.

Comment: Nothing comes to mind. You're probably thinking of the ignition switch harness which is around that area.

Comment: @Ben I am thinking that's exactly it. For some reason I wanted to believe that they were separate issues... But it seems they are one in the same.